# dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 4; 2 is required

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm new here and django world..
I tried to find an answer about this error, but I didn't find one that fix my problem.

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^menu_direcao/', "academico.views.menu_direcao", name='menu_direçao'),
    url(r'^menu_direcao/add_prof/', "academico.views.add_prof", name='add_prof'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('', (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class AddProfessor(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    sobrenome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    nascimento = models.DateField()
    matricula = models.IntegerField(max_length=20)
    senha = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from academico.models import AddProfessor

class FormAddProfessor(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AddProfessor
        fields = 'nome', 'sobrenome', 'nascimento', 'matricula'
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from django.template import RequestContext
from academico.models import AddProfessor
from academico.forms import FormAddProfessor

def menu(request):
    return render_to_response("menu_temp.html", context_instance = RequestContext(request))

def menu_direcao(request):
    return render_to_response("menu_direcao.html", context_instance = RequestContext(request))

def add_prof(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = FormAddProfessor(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render_to_response("salvo.html", {})
    else:
    form = FormAddProfessor()
    return render_to_response("add_professor.html", {'form', form}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

**template/add_prof.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block corpo %}

<form action="" method="POST">

    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}

    <button type="submit">Adicionar</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

**ERROR:**

```
ValueError at /menu_direcao/add_prof/
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 4; 2 is required
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/menu_direcao/add_prof/
Django Version: 1.8.5
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 4; 2 is required
Exception Location: C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py in __init__, line 20
Python Executable:  C:\Python34\python.exe
Python Version: 3.4.2
Python Path:    
['c:\\Python34\\Scripts\\escola',
 'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python34.zip',
 'C:\\Python34\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib',
 'C:\\Python34',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Dom, 18 Out 2015 12:50:21 -0200
```

**TRACEBACK:**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/menu_direcao/add_prof/

Django Version: 1.8.5
Python Version: 3.4.2
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'academico')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "c:\Python34\Scripts\escola\academico\views.py" in add_prof
  49.       context_instance = RequestContext(request))
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render_to_response
  45.             using=using)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  115.                         template_name, context, context_instance, dirs, dictionary)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py" in render_to_string
  220.         with context_instance.push(context):
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py" in push
  55.         return ContextDict(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py" in __init__
  20.         super(ContextDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: ValueError at /menu_direcao/add_prof/
Exception Value: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 4; 2 is required
```

So, if you can help me, I'll be very greateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def add_prof(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = FormAddProfessor(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request, "salvo.html")
    else:
        form = FormAddProfessor()
        return render(request, "add_professor.html", {'form': form})
```